# How do I wrap Laravel eloquent conditions to create the following query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a simple results table that looks like the following -

```
id, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_score, away_score, media
1       511          322            4           0       'a4vw'
2       232          511            2           2       'bf34',
3       111          511            2           3        NULL
```

I am able to get all the rows where 'team_id' value is either the `home_team_id` OR `away_team_id` = `511`, but I also need to check to ensure that the `media` column is `NOT NULL`
The raw SQL query would like like this

```
SELECT * FROM results where (home_team_id = 310718 OR away_team_id = 310718) and media is not null;
```

However I am trying to use the Laravel Eloquent approach as much as possible as I'm learning this so could use one approach like the following (which works fine) but i'm trying to not use any `DB::raw` methods in my approach

```
DB::table("results")
->where(DB::raw("(home_team_id = 511 or away_team_id = 511)"))
->whereNotNull("media")
->get();
```

How would I amend the following in my Results model to perform the same query as the queries above as this returns all the results I only expect 2 results as media column has a single NULL entry

```
return Result::where('home_team_id', '=', $clubId)
             ->orWhere('away_team_id', '=', $clubId)
             ->whereNotNull('media')
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your query is the use of the `orWhere` condition in the wrong position. As there are two main conditions in your query one is

> 'team_id' value is either the `home_team_id` OR `away_team_id`

while the second condition is

> `media` column is NOT NULL

So you will have to break down your two conditions into two separate conditional statements.

Try the following query

```
return Result::where(function($query) use ($clubId) {
   $query->where('home_team_id', '=', $clubId)
         ->orWhere('away_team_id', '=', $clubId);
})
->whereNotNull('media')
->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this please?

```
return Result::where(function($query) use ($clubId) {
            $query->where('home_team_id', $clubId)
                ->orWhere('away_team_id', $clubId);
        })->whereNotNull('media')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a common mistake among beginners.

> You should always group `orWhere` calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping